# Anchor tag with an hashtag directs to external tab

Tags: html

I'm beginner, and trying to do a small task of referring to an interval link like this:

```html
<h2 id="myId"> Hello <h2>


<div style="margin-top:600px">
<a href="#myId">Go to Hello header</a>
</div>
```

And for some reason it throws me away to an external tab with the site's address concatenated with #myId.

Comment: What browser are you using? The code looks fine and works for me

Comment: i'm using firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `target="_self"`

```
<a href="#myId" target="_self">
```